# How to prevent Html showing before knockout binding is executed

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the following knockout scripts in my Html:

```
<!-- kno ifnot: bla -->

 <tr><td>some stuff</td></tr>

<!-- /ko -->
```

The problem I have is that before the bindings are executed this row will show for a second or two.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Here's a simple trick.  Just make your root element initially hidden and set the visible binding to true.

```
<div style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true">
    <!-- the rest of your stuff -->
</div>
```

As it's rendered, before knockout does its thing, it will be initially hidden.  When the bindings are applied, knockout will override the style and make it visible.

---

Alternatively, you can throw your view into a script block and instantiate it through a template.  The script blocks will not be rendered but will be visible when knockout renders the template.

```
<!-- ko template: 'myView' --><!-- /ko -->
<script id="myView" type="text/html">
    <!-- the rest of your stuff -->
</script>
```

Comment: I like this better than Tom's solution as it relies only on knockout to unhide the HTML.

Comment: exactly what i ended up doing (then checked back here and same solution ;S)

Comment: This doesn't work for me when using bootstrap `d-none`.

Comment: Note that this only works if you use the _inline_ style to set `display: none`. (Background: Hiding the element via class style does not work since Knockout _removes_ the `display` inline style when making the element visible via binding. Then your class style will take over and hide the element forever.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the behavior you want often varies from page to page - this is what I am doing in my layout/template file (ASP.NET).

```
 <div class="ko-unbound" data-bind="css: { 'ko-unbound': false, 'ko-bound': true }">
    @RenderBody()
 </div>
```

When the page is bound:

- `ko-unbound` class is removed from the page (initially added with `class` attribute).
- `ko-bound` class is added to the page.

Then in a page where unwanted content is a problem I can customize the css to show or hide things based on these two classes. I also use this technique to show a 'loading' image or perhaps impose a minimum height for an element.

```
.ko-unbound #storeWizard
{
    display: none;  // hide entire section when the page is binding
}

.ko-bound #loadingGraphic
{
    display: none;  // hide loading graphic after page is bound
}
```

During testing, when applying bindings I add a timeout so I can see the flash.

```
 setTimeout(function ()
 {
     ko.applyBindings(RR.VM);

 }, 300);
```

Comment: This is a relatively nice solution, with lots of promise, although it would be nicer as a re-usable knockout binding.  We would need to make sure it is the first binding evaluated, though.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your html in something like this -

```
<div id="hideme" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript, add the following jquery line after your apply binding -

```
$('#hideme').show();
```

This is simplest method that I've found that works.  You could do this with some knockout bindings, but you lose guaranteed timing because you cannot control order bindings are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which I found [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/773)

```
<div id="binding-start" style="visibility:hidden" data-bind="attr: { 'style': 'visibility:visible' }" />
```

This has the advantage - or disadvantage, depending on your needs - that space will be reserved for the hidden content. The page will not "jump" when the bindings are applied.

Answer (score 0):

**You might be doing it wrong.** Here's what worked for me.

The cause for me was that I was calling `ko.applyBindings()` after my data had been pulled down over the wire.

I use TypeScript to make a bunch of classes which are the models in an MVVM kinda way. I construct and populate these models using JSON from an API.

If you're also working in this way, then seeing the template HTML for a second or more is a sign you could be doing things in a bad order.

So, on your root view model add an `isLoading` observable boolean default to `true`.

Add a `populate(data)` method on your root view model which takes your JSON and populates the model and sets `isLoading(false)` at the end.

Bind a wrapper `<div data-bind="ifnot: isLoading"> ... content`

Move the `ko.applyBindings(rootViewModel)` call to the earliest opportunity so it initializes and hides that `div`.

Then call your API, get the JSON and chuck it into `rootViewModel.populate(data)`.

You're almost done. You'll now get a very quick flash of HTML, so add a fade-in transition to this wrapper div and you're good to go.

Have fun!