# Binding problems with complex data and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout JS 3.2 and I'd like to use it with autocomplete dropdown.  I'm not able to get around two problems.

I simplified the data and code so this runs stand-alone:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [
            { "User": { "Id": 1, "DisplayName": "john a" }, "Roles": [{ "Id": 1, "Name": "admins" }, { "Id": 2, "Name": "users" }] },
            { "User": { "Id": 2, "DisplayName": "john b" }, "Roles": [] },
            { "User": { "Id": 3, "DisplayName": "john c" }, "Roles": [{ "Id": 1, "Name": "admins" }] },
            { "User": { "Id": 4, "DisplayName": "john d" }, "Roles": [] },
            { "User": { "Id": 5, "DisplayName": "john e" }, "Roles": [{ "Id": 2, "Name": "users" }] }
    ];

    $(function () {
        $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(ui.item);
                    ko.cleanNode($("#userDetails")[0]);
                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#userDetails")[0]);
                }
            }
        })
        .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
              .append("<a>" + item.User.DisplayName + "</a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
</script>


<div>Select User: <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" /></div>

<div id="userDetails">
    <div>User: <span data-bind="text: User.DisplayName"></span></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: Roles, visible: Roles().length > 0">
        <div><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problems:

1. I'd like to show the `userDetails` div only when it's bound -- hide it on page load.   I tried setting `style="display:none"` and then `data-bind="if:User"` or `data-bind="if:User.Id"`.  Setting display attribute hides the element on load, but it doesn't change on bind.
2. Roles element binding doesn't work right.  On first time that user is selected, the roles show, but they fail to show after changing the user selection.

Comment: [problem 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13168767/390278)

Comment: Instead of always rebinding why don't you have a proper view model with a selecteduser property and just update that in the automcomplete handler? With this approach you can use the `with` binding and it also solvers your both problems: http://jsfiddle.net/74mvbkme/

Comment: your comment looks apt than my answer i deleted mine . please add your comment as answer . cheers

Comment: You should also use a bindingHandler for the autocomplete (either find one online or create your own) instead of adding the autocomplete on document load.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always rebinding you need to have a proper view model with a `selectedUser` property and just update that one in the automcomplete handler.

```
var viewModel = {
    selectedUser: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#userDetails")[0]);

$(function () {
    $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                var user = ko.mapping.fromJS(ui.item);
                viewModel.selectedUser(user);                                       
            }
        }
    })
    .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
          .append("<a>" + item.User.DisplayName + "</a>")
          .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

With this approach you can use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) and it will also solve both of your problems:

```
<div id="userDetails" data-bind="with: selectedUser">
    <div>User: <span data-bind="text: User.DisplayName"></span></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: Roles, visible: Roles().length > 0">
        <div><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74mvbkme/).