# How to use Knockout Visible binding correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

In [the first part of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169616/2946486) it says to apply the following code to prevent the HTML from being displayed while the Knockout bindings are applied:

```
<div style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true">
    <!-- the rest of your stuff -->
</div>
```

The author states:

> As it's rendered, before knockout does its thing, it will be initially hidden. When the bindings are applied, knockout will override the style and make it visible.

Is this correct? Would this `div` not be permanently hidden due to the `true` value allowing the `CSS` `display: none` to apply? How could you make it visible after the bindings are applied?

[In the Knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html), it states:

> When the parameter resolves to a true-like value (e.g., the boolean value true, or a non-null object or array), the binding removes the yourElement.style.display value, causing it to become visible.
>
> Note that any display style you’ve configured using CSS will then apply (so CSS rules like display:table-row work fine in conjunction with this binding).

Comment: Yes, it is correct. This approach actually worked for me

Comment: It does seem to contradict the documentation, unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: looks perfectly ok for me @tallpaul . `visible:true` binding will remove the display prop on element only if display is `not` configured with css sample here switch b/w display `none & any css class` to observe the difference  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27691/.

Answer (score 1):

The Knockout documentation is slightly wrong. It should state that the `visible` binding will revert to the `display` setting of the *CSS rules*, rather than just "CSS". So it would become:

> Note that any display style you’ve configured in your CSS rules will then apply (so CSS rules like `x { display:table-row }` work fine in conjunction with this binding).